# Android Studio 3.1.3 strange behavior when add new activity

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, android-studio-3.1

Just started on this new existing project.
When i tried to add a new activity, or add new dependency, the whole project seems to loose all the dependencies. When i tried to run it says i need to select Android SDK.

I have tried everything, Sync project with gradle files, invalidate caches, even reinstalling AS. Deleted .gradle dir, deleted android sdk, everything related the AS has been removed and reinstalled and still got the problem.

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TXT1o.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After hours trying many things, i realized it was my android studio kotlin plugin outdated.

Answer (score 1):

Did you check File > Project Structure in Android Studio if the right SDK is selected?
Also check if you have any special configuration in your local.properties file.